# proxy works fine with http but not https

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, https, python-requests

I wanted to use proxies in python requests but when I run the code with like this

```
req = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies={'https': 'user:pass@host:port',
                                                 'http': 'user:pass@host:port'})
print(req.content)
```

I get this error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None
```

but If I use "http://httpbin.org/ip" instead of "https://httpbin.org/ip"

it works really fine

and in other stuff like if I run this code

```
proxies = { 'http' : 'user:pass@host:port' }
req =requests.get("https://lumtest.com/myip.json",proxies =proxies )
print(req.content)
```

I get my ip address which means that the proxies are not working. But if I use this
which is the same url just without the s in https and I run it over HTTP

```
proxies = { 'http' : 'user:pass@host:port' }
req =requests.get("http://lumtest.com/myip.json",proxies =proxies )
print(req.content)
```

I get the ip of the proxy which means that its working fine

It doesn't bother me changing the s in HTTP or HTTPS but in some website when I use proxies over HTTP
I get a different response I get this

```
b''
```

instead of getting the response that I wanted that works fine without proxies even If I run it on HTTPS or HTTP

but If I run it it only works over http with the proxies and it doesn't give me a valid response

I hope someone can help me bcuz I have been trying to solve this forever

Comment: This can be many issues but If I have to guess I would say that you do not have good quality proxies. Also sometimes some website protections like cloudflare blocks proxy connections and then made a redirection. You should take a look at the response code to have better infos

Comment: What kind of proxy do u suggest

Comment: can u give me a name for a good proxy provider

Comment: I'm using luminati btw

Comment: Last time I've played with proxy I was using something like this https://github.com/trimstray/multitor#docker